# Avoiding copies of large objects within functions

Tags: r, function, memory

Let `biglist` be a quite big object:

```
biglist <- rep(1,10000000) # 76.3 Mb
```

Then manipulate data in a fictitious function which itself calls another fictitious function

```
funx <- function(x) {
  return(funy(x+1))
}
funy <- function(y) {
  return(y+1)
}
biglist <- funx(biglist)
```

If I would like to manipulate `biglist`, how to prevent having several instance of `biglist` (in `.Global` environment, within `funx` and within `funy`) and thus avoid filling the memory of the laptop (with even larger objects)?

Comment: Have you tried the `eval.parent(substitute(x<-x+1))` ?

Comment: R doesn't like to do modifications by reference. That kind of goes against one of the paradigms of functional programming languages. If you need to modify in place you might want to look at a different language.

Comment: I have tried to use Global variables, but finally I would like to get rid of them. But if I try to avoid Global variables, I end up into these memory eating questions. The code @storaged provided is something new to me, but I suspect that such a method would be working when the data manipulations are more complex. Should I stick to continue manipulating Global variables?